# How to version answers to questions over time

Tags: discussion

What is the correct way to version answers over time?  Specifically, when the correct answer to a question changes in a way which makes the original answer (possibly with 100 upvotes) wrong?

You could downvote the now incorrect answer, but this takes time and hurts the reputation of the original answerer.

You could request it be deleted, but the answerer may be unavailable now or not want to lose the rep.

You could argue that questions should be versioned (have the asker include specific version numbers in some way), but this isn't always possible.

Are there any other ideas, and has any Q+A site solved this issue?

Comment: Write a new answer for the new version. Edit the old answer to indicate it is for the old version only and things have changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I come across answers like this, I just leave a comment- something to the effect of "This no longer applies, because (reasons)."

If I know the updated answer (and it hasn't already been posted), I write a new answer and reference my new answer in the old answer's comment; "This no longer applies because X. See my answer for an updated solution."